# Elasticsearch curl get all tour id from query which requires departureCityId and destinationCountryId

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data as such

```
"_source": {
                    "id": "00000000-0000-0188-0000-000000023d07",
                    "departureDestination": {
                        "departureCityId": 392,
                        "destinationCountryId": 146695
                    },
                    "tours": [
                        {
                            "id": 146696,
                            "name": "Рига",
                            "fromCityId": 392
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 521347,
                            "name": "Экскурсионные туры - Рига",
                            "fromCityId": 392
                        },
 ],
                    "hotels": [
                        {
                            "id": 312821,
                            "name": "ALBERT HOTEL 4 *",
                            "tourId": 146696
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 310637,
                            "name": "AMBER SEA HOTEL & SPA 4 *",
                            "tourId": 519120
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 310902,
                            "name": "AMBER SPA BOUTIQUE HOTEL 4 *",
                            "tourId": 519120
                        }

_source": {
                    "id": "00000000-0000-0188-0000-0000000259a4",
                    "departureDestination": {
                        "departureCityId": 392,
                        "destinationCountryId": 154020
                    },
                    "tours": [
                        {
                            "id": 585494,
                            "name": "Адриатика - Апулия",
                            "fromCityId": 392
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 517867,
                            "name": "Адриатика - Каттолика",
                            "fromCityId": 392
                        }
"hotels": [
                        {
                            "id": 9011932,
                            "name": "ABAMAR (RIMINI) 3 *",
                            "tourId": 9013222
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 240190,
                            "name": "ABANO GRAND HOTEL (ABANO TERME) 5* Deluxe",
                            "tourId": 383920
                        }
```

I want to write a request that returns tours id  for the field that match "departureCityId" 
I wrote a query as but it returns no hit and how do i make it return only ID

```
such curl -X GET "localhost:9200/countries_reference_book/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query": {"dis_max": {"queries": [{ "match": { "departureCityId":392}},{ "match"{"destinationCountryId":146695}}],"tie_breaker": 0.3}}}'
```

I want user to enter two parameter departureCityId and destinationCountryId and it should return only id of tours. from the json above if the user enters   392 and 146695 respectively it should return

```
"tours": [
                        {
                            "id": 146696,
                            "name": "Рига",
                            "fromCityId": 392
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 521347,
                            "name": "Экскурсионные туры - Рига",
                            "fromCityId": 392
                        },
```

MY index

```
{
    "countries_reference_book": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "countriesreferencebook": {
                "properties": {
                    "departureDestination": {
                        "properties": {
                            "departureCityId": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "destinationCountryId": {
                                "type": "long"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "hotels": {
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "tourId": {
                                "type": "long"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "regions": {
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "tours": {
                        "properties": {
                            "fromCityId": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
```

Comment: @Val what do you think about this

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: get all tour id from query which requires departureCityId and destinationCountryId

Comment: @MartinSchulze i wrote that above but my query is not right

Comment: Please provide the mapping of your index.

Comment: I provided it right now please check @MartinSchulze

Comment: To query for elements in tours the type of tours should be nested. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: @MartinSchulze yes probably something like this curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{ "match": { "departureDestination.departureCityId": "392" }},{ "match": { "departureDestination.destinationCountryId":  "146695" }}]}}}'

Comment: @MartinSchulze but can you help write a query that does that and returns only tour id - the file is id in tour object

Comment: No, you have to change your mapping of the index. The tours mapping type should be nested. Then you can query for documents with a specific tour.

Comment: ok can you give an example , that would be great i am very new to es